# WWW.bytesDownloaded doesnt update while loading

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

In my script im expecting the text `bytesDownloadedText` to be updated with how many bytes have been downloaded so far but it only runs once and stays on 0. How do I fix this

```c#
private IEnumerator DownloadFile(){
        WWW w = new WWW (PATH_TO_DOWNLOAD);

        bytesDownloadedText.text = w.bytesDownloaded.ToString();

        yield return w;

        if (w.error != null) {
            Debug.LogError ("Error: " + w.error);
        } else {
            scriptText = w.text;
            filesDownloaded = true;
            Debug.Log (scriptText);
        }
    }
```

**Edit**: New code + Additional debugging information

```c#
private IEnumerator DownloadFile(){
        WWW w = new WWW (PATH_TO_DOWNLOAD);

        while(!w.isDone){
            bytesDownloadedText.text = w.bytesDownloaded.ToString ();
            Debug.Log ("Bytes Downloaded: " + w.bytesDownloaded);

            yield return null;
        }

        Debug.Log ("Exiting while loop");

        if (w.error != null) {
            Debug.LogError ("Error: " + w.error);
        } else {
            //bytesDownloadedText.text = w.bytesDownloaded.ToString ();
            scriptText = w.text;
            filesDownloaded = true;
            Debug.Log (scriptText);
        }
    }
```

1. Filesize: 337 bytes
2. Download Path: https://deathcrow.altervista.org/websharp/files.php

3.Code where `DownloadFile` is called

```c#
private void Start(){
        StartCoroutine (DownloadFile ());
    }
```

4. The while loop is exiting
5. w.text returns the test script from the server(which is code)

```html
using UnityEngine;

public class TestScript: MonoBehaviour{
 public void Update(){
  if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
   RaycastHit hit;
   if (Physics.Raycast (Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition),out hit)){
    if (hit.transform.tag == "Destroy") {
     Destroy (hit.transform.root.gameObject);
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Edit: Online code

```php
<?
    $scriptText = "";

    $file_handle = fopen("TestScript.cs","r");
    while(!feof($file_handle)){
        $line = fgets($file_handle);
        $scriptText = $scriptText . $line;
    }
    fclose($file_handle);

    $size = strlen($scriptText);

    header("Content-length: ".$size);

    echo $scriptText;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not yield `WWW` if you want to use the `bytesDownloaded` property as that will pause your code until `WWW` returns which makes it impossible to read how much data has been downloaded.

You have to put `WWW.bytesDownloaded` in a loop then use `WWW.isDone` to detect when `WWW` is done and then exit the loop. Inside that loop, you can use `WWW.bytesDownloaded` to display the downloaded data. Finally, you must wait for a frame after each loop so that other scripts can execute or Unity will freeze until the download is done.

This is what that code should look like:

```
private IEnumerator DownloadFile()
{
    WWW w = new WWW(PATH_TO_DOWNLOAD);

    while (!w.isDone)
    {
        yield return null;
        bytesDownloadedText.text = w.bytesDownloaded.ToString();
        Debug.Log("Bytes Downloaded: " + w.bytesDownloaded);
    }

    if (w.error != null)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Error: " + w.error);
    }
    else
    {
        scriptText = w.text;
        filesDownloaded = true;
        Debug.Log(scriptText);
    }
}
```

---

<sup>**Note:**  There are some instances where the `bytesDownloaded` property returns `0`. This has nothing to do with Unity. This happens mostly when your server is not sending the `Content-Length` header.</sup>

Example of sending the `Content-Length` header from the server(php):

```
<?php
  //String to send
  $data = "Test message to send";
  //Get size
  $size= strlen($data);
  //Set Content-length header
  header("Content-length: ".$size);
  //Finally, you can send the data
  echo $data;
?>
```

Comment: it is still returning 0 in the console, I have updated the question to include the php code used on the server

Comment: its 339 bytes after adding the header `content-length`  But i have put the `yield return null` before `WWW.bytesDownloaded` but it is still returning `0` every frame untill the download is complete in which it returns `339`

Comment: It's fine now. It's doing this because the data is too small so they all return at once. Try about 20mb data and you'll see that it works fine.